# n-1 Independent events , but no n-wise independent examples

Tags: probability

For all n ≥ 3, construct an example of a probability space
$(Ω_n, P_n)$ and events $A_1, A_2, . . . , A_n$ such that $P(A_i) = 1/2$
for each i, any n − 1 of the events are independent, but the n events are not independent.
Can anyone help me construct a concrete example for me? I've been keeping constructing mutually independent events for an hour....

(I tried to use the example of dividing n people into 2 groups...but this does not work well)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider independent random variables $(X_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n-1}$ such that $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=-1)=\frac12$ for every $i$ and define $A_i=[X_i=1]$ for every $1\leqslant i\leqslant n-1$. Then $A_n=[$ $___$ $=1]$ fits the bill.

Thus, one can choose $\Omega_n=\{-1,1\}^{n-1}$ with the uniform probability $P_n$ and $X_i:\Omega_n\to\{-1,1\}$ the projection on the $i$th coordinate, for every $1\leqslant i\leqslant n-1$.

Comment: I am sorry but I still do not have idea about the $A_n$ guy...